# American commercial 240 volt microwave oven in American residence

Tags: electrical, kitchens, 240v, microwave-oven, usa

There's been a few questions about using foreign 240 volt kitchen appliances, teakettles from UK seems to be a popular one, in the USA but I haven't seen any about domestic 240 volt appliances in the USA, with the obvious exception of ranges, ovens, and cook tops.  The reason why this is being considered is the same, envy over other nations getting their tea (or whatever) hot more quickly than is available in the USA because they use 240 volt appliances and we use 120 volt appliances.  This isn't strictly true, there are 240 volt small kitchen appliances but they are almost exclusively used commercially.

There's a more general question to consider but to keep this from getting too open ended I'll consider keeping this to a microwave oven but this could easily apply to a refrigerator, coffee maker, rice cooker, and so on.  It could be most anything that heats food in a relatively short amount of time, or perhaps something with a particularly large motor that would be typical in a commercial kitchen but atypical in a residential kitchen.

The goal is to keep everything up to code, and that is a big part why only domestic appliances are being considered, it removes any issues of violating some safety code in the USA.  Having 240 volt outlets in a kitchen installed and approved is likely to be an unusual request for contractors and inspectors meaning they will have questions for me and I'd like to have answers for them if I or someone I know wants to follow through on the idea.

There's four situations that could come up, a "major" or "minor" renovation on a microwave oven in a "cubbyhole" or on a countertop.  A "minor" renovation is merely changing out the outlet and possibly the circuit breaker without any changes to the wires in the wall.  A "major" renovation means opening up the wall to allow for new wires, this includes a new build.  A "cubbyhole" is having a shelf and circuit dedicated to a microwave oven, including an install of a hardwired appliance.  On the countertop should be self evident, I bring in the microwave, put it on the kitchen counter, plug it in, and use it.  The countertop case is the most generic case and could most readily apply to a 240 volt coffee maker, teakettle, or something as well.

I assume most locations are like mine where if there is a cubbyhole for a microwave oven then building code requires a dedicated circuit for it.  This means in a minor renovation the 120 volt outlet and circuit breaker are replaced with 240 volt versions.  This assumes 12/2+G NM wire or something largely equivalent in place.  Easy and done, right?  This should not raise any flags from an inspection, agreed?  <strike>A 14/2+G wire would not suffice as I have not seen any 240 volt microwave ovens with a 6-15 plug, they will have a 6-20 or 6-30 plug.</strike> I have found microwave ovens using a 6-15 plug since posting, so that's an option.

If doing this "right" with a major renovation then I'd look for a 10/3+G wire from the breaker box to the cubbyhole, the neutral capped off and a 6-20 or 6-30 outlet as appropriate for the specific model of microwave oven.  I'd have the neutral wire in case there's a change of plans later and the cubbyhole is repurposed for a convection oven or a 5-20 duplex outlet for any of a variety of uses.  One such reuse of the cubbyhole is a bog-standard 120 volt microwave oven.  This works "backwards" too, I can put in the bog-standard 120 volt microwave from the start but have the wires in the wall in case of a decision to install a "heavy duty" microwave oven or convection oven.  Or perhaps I assume too much on meeting building code?

A minor renovation for a countertop 240 volt microwave is not likely to fly.  I could likely make it "work" if there's an existing pair of 20 amp 120 volt circuits with a shared neutral and common trip breaker (or a common trip breaker can be fitted to circuits at the breaker box).  By "work" I mean I could replace a 5-15 or 5-20 duplex outlet with a 6-20 outlet and not create an obvious safety hazard, and if the inspector isn't looking too closely it might pass inspection.  The intent on having countertop 120 volt outlets wired as required is so two large power consuming appliances can be used at once without a safety hazard or circuit breaker trip.  If the one 240 volt microwave oven (or coffee maker, or whatever) takes all the power then any other load on that breaker could cause a trip.  The goal is to cook faster all at once, and this is not getting anyone there.

If there is a major renovation in place then there's no grandfather clause to hide behind.  Getting the dream of a hot cup of whatever perks you up in the time only 240 volts can get means running a circuit for it that is completely separate from the requisite 120 volt outlets.  Or so it appears to me.  I'm thinking having a single 240 volt circuit with something like 1 or 2 duplex 6-20 outlets would pass inspection, again this is in addition to the requisite 120 volt outlets.  The argument for allowing more than one outlet on the circuit, where this might not be allowed in a commercial kitchen, is that it is unlikely for more than one 240 volt appliance to be operating at a time in a residential kitchen.  With outlets in more than one location it gives freedom on where the microwave oven ends up, and it allows for adding a 240 volt coffee maker, rice cooker, or whatever later on without having to unplug and reconnect appliances each time.  If running 12/3+G cable to the boxes (as opposed to 12/2+G) then it leaves the option to have a 5-20 duplex outlet in one or more of the electrical boxes for extra 120 volt appliances on the countertop with that added circuit breaker.  That is assuming building code allows, which I believe it does.

I know that is a lot but I wanted to show my thought process, that I did at least some minimal research and thinking on this, that I covered what should be the most obvious pitfalls and options, and a desire to keep this from creating a safety hazard.  Would I actually go through with any of this?  I believe I would.  It looks like a minimal added expense to complete and I'd have a nice commercial grade appliance or two for cooking at home.  If done right then it should add some tangible value to the home if or when I sell, and gives ideas on what to look for in a new-to-me home should I want to bring those commercial grade 240 volt appliances with me.

Comment: As long as the receptacle/wires/breaker are all 240 volts it will be in code.  The problem will be re selling if the new people need 120 volt receptacles, but code requires this for kitchens anyway.  The 240s might be seen as not needed/an eye sore/a PITA to get rid of.

Comment: Personal anecdote: Last year I ran a new 12/3 from a 20A 2-pole breaker to a duplex 6-20R at my new 'coffee bar' just outside of my kitchen so I can plug in my South African Russell-Hobbs 3kW kettle. Boils a cuppa in little over 30 seconds ;) Afaik my installation is (probably) to code, but I have no idea if I was "allowed" to cut off the original giant SA 15A plug (roughly the same size as a UK 13A one) and replace it with a 6-15P.

Comment: You didn't do much research if you think there are no 240V receptacles in the average American kitchen.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Did you read the first sentence where I pointed out the exception for stoves, ovens, and ranges?  I edited the first paragraph to indicate "small appliances" as opposed to just "appliances" in an effort to prevent future confusion.  I'm pretty sure 240 volt microwave ovens are not common in residential kitchens in the USA.

Comment: Are the appliances happy with 60Hz? A range may not care, but a microwave may have issues.

Comment: You said, quote: *"Having 240 volt outlets in a kitchen installed and approved is likely to be an unusual request for contractors and inspectors"*

Comment: @brhans the only tangible issue with the ZA kettle is that from a safety perspective it's designed so that there are 0V between the neutral conductors and earthed parts.  When you plug it in to your outlet there are 120V between (what ought to be) the neutral and earth.  You would have to ask the designers if that presents a safety issue.    IDK, for example, if it's cordless maybe the neutral pin on the base is not protected as well as it ought to be if it is 120V to earth.   A two-pole GFCI breaker on this circuit would go a long way to eliminating unknown dangers.

Comment: An outlet for a $3000 microwave oven will not add resale value to a home.  Your buyer would have to exhaust every other more common way of adding $3000 to your kitchen, it would have to be a $200,000 kitchen at least, before throwing $3000 at a microwave would seem "valuable".  And **that** buyer would not be swayed one way or another buy a $200 outlet.  Not that you shouldn't do it for YOU, if you will get joy out of it ... just not for the resale value.

Comment: Don't know SA, but people from the Euro-zone who are probably asleep right now have stated that appliances there need to be safe with 240V to ground present on either L or N (since some areas use unpolarized plugs.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal oh no you just took this project off my back burner.  Almost literally :)

Comment: "Are the appliances happy with 60Hz?"  Yes, they are UL approved and such for the USA market but not typically sold to homeowners, only commercial kitchens.  "An outlet for a $3000 microwave oven will not add resale value to a home."  This is considered in part since it appears having a convection oven is popular, as opposed to *conventional* oven but having more than one of those seems popular too.  "just not for the resale value"  This might not add to resale value but it is unlikely to subtract, the value add is likely in selling sooner rather than for a higher price.

Comment: Do as you will, but if you think it adds tangible value (speed or money), have a conversation with a few realtors about it. I’d bet money that they’re neutral at best on the plan.

Comment: This post is entirely too long. It should be half as long at most, but probably even shorter.

Comment: If this question is "opinion based" then every question here is "opinion based".  I lay out four possible options for wiring up a 240 volt outlet and I ask if they all meet building code.  That would be in the "opinion" of the reader, I guess, but then if that's how "opinion based" is defined then every question on StackExchange is opinion based.

Comment: TL;DR. Cut it down to "this is my goal, what's a code-approved way to achieve it". (Not even "the best", if you want to keep the overeager people from sniping at the Opinion button). (I'd have voted "needs more focus", not "opinion")

Comment: A point to consider on being "overeager" on closing questions. If I have a question closed for some reason, and it's been down voted because of similarly "overeager" voters, what motivations do I have to edit this question? I have no assurances that it would be re-opened after editing. But I could keep "spamming" the site with variations on the same question, each starting at zero votes by the way rather than down voted, until I get my answer because it wasn't hastily closed for being "opinion based". If left open then people can still answer, even if this is an "opinion" in their "opinion".

Comment: If you keep asking the same question, the new ones will probably be closed as dupes. If you edit it down to a reasonable question, it's likely to be reopened - we're pretty good about that here. Of course, _you_ have no assurance of that until you try, but  having hung out here for a number of years, you have _my_ reassurance that we're a generally reasonable bunch.

Comment: "but having hung out here for a number of years"  I've come and gone for years, not "hung out".  I still don't know how this thing is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with having 240V receptacles in the kitchen or in any other part of the house. Plenty of people do that all the time for things that other people would consider unusual:

- Workshop - welder, table saw and other power tools
- Computers - personal server farm, etc.
- EVSE (a.k.a., car charging) - this is now becoming normal, but just a few years ago it was unusual

There are three ways to install a 240V circuit:

- Dedicated to a particular appliance (whether hardwired or plug/receptacle) - this should pose no special code issues at all
- Multiple receptacles
- Multi-Wire Branch Circuit - specifically 15A/20A, *shared with 120V receptacles*

The only real issue I see when it comes to multiple receptacles is that you can't count these receptacles in place of other required receptacles (kitchen countertop receptacles every 4', around the walls of each room every 12', etc.) and they can't count as a required circuit. A kitchen is required to have 2 circuits serving the countertop receptacles. Even if you have enough 120V receptacles from one circuit to cover all the required areas, I don't think you could get away with using your 240V circuit as the second required circuit.

An MWBC gets really interesting. On the one hand, an MWBC, by definition, can have both 120V (x2!) and 240V receptacles. On the other hand, an inspector may not look too fondly on an MWBC that includes 240V receptacles if it effectively uses up one - or possibly both! - of your required kitchen countertop receptacle circuits when you turn on that single 240V appliance. In addition, MWBC used in this way would limit you to 15A or 20A 240V appliances. If you want to have any 240V 30A appliances they will need their own circuits anyway.

So to play it safe:

- Add additional 240V or MWBC 120V/240V circuits to support your 240V appliances.
- Make sure you have the appropriate required 120V circuits (number of circuits, location of receptacles).
- For any hardwired devices, make sure they are UL or ETL listed or try, in some fashion, to get them approved by your local jurisdiction. For plugin devices you are largely on your own and while your insurance company may care if something goes wrong, your local jurisdiction (permits, inspection, etc.) normally only goes as far as the receptacle unless an appliance is hardwired.
- The NEC has been including GFCI requirements for more and more 240V circuits in each code cycle. Even if your state does not currently require 240V kitchen receptacles to be GFCI protected, I highly recommend you protect them, which generally means GFCI/breaker as I am not aware of any generally available 240V GFCI/receptacles.

Comment: I will have to look into if GFCI would be required.  I suspect not if there's a "cubbyhole" install but could be required for a countertop install.

Comment: It used to be based on < 6' from water. NEC has been seriously expanding it, to the extent of including pretty much everything in a kitchen. Really. A few years ago (and in many states still today) you would be 100% correct as long as >6' from sink.

Comment: "If you want to have any 240V 30A appliances they will need their own circuits anyway."  Good point, this would not be considered outside the "cubbyhole" install option for all kinds of reasons.  Is there a proper name for what I'm calling a "cubbyhole"?

Comment: My take on what you are referring to as a "cubbyhole" is a designated structured place in the kitchen for a specific appliance. Similar to, but not necessarily as close a fit, a typical built-in wall oven. (That's typical - mine is in a brick wall, which was a fun adventure...) Though the truth is I have a countertop oven in a specific location that is *almost* a cubbyhole, but the circuit is shared with some other receptacles in the kitchen - and in any case it is standard 120V.

Answer (score 1):

The kitchen is a place where 240V outlets are bog standard in USA/Canada.

However, in many cases it will be an NEC article 110 part I C 3.1.1 violation to install commercial appliances in a residence, as they often state that they are **only** to be installed in commercial environments, and thus installing one in a residential setting is violating the manufacturer's instructions. Your local inspector may not care, but if you ever have a claim, your insurance company will be delighted to have a reason to deny coverage since it violates both the UL (or ETL) listing and the NEC to ignore the manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: "The kitchen is a place where 240V outlets are bog standard in USA/Canada."  I still see houses in the USA that don't have 240VAC service.  There's no 240V outlets in the kitchen, none in the home, it's not even possible without a new service line run from the utility.  Granted these are old homes but it is clear that 120V outlets are the norm.  How does a house in the USA still not have 240V service?  The stove and other heating is natural gas, and if there is air conditioning then it is a small enough home and/or cool enough environment that a 120V air conditioner is considered comfortable.

Comment: 120V service? That would be very rare and antique indeed, if it's even the case at all. While there may be no 240V devices, standard distribution from pole to building in the USA & Canada is 240V center-tapped. Even with 60A service and actual FUSES!

Comment: Has anyone got in any kind of trouble anywhere in the USA for having a 240 volt microwave oven in their kitchen?  What kind of commercial kitchen appliances have got people in trouble?  I don't want to get any of those so I don't get in trouble.  I'm thinking pretty mundane stuff like a coffee maker and rice cooker, not a meat slicer that can cut an entire cow in half in one swipe.  My family likes coffee and so they drink plenty when they get together, it would be nice to have a big pot ready at breakfast and again about 3:00PM.  Maybe two pots, some prefer decaf.

Comment: Read the instructions. If they don't *restrict to commercial* or *forbid residential,* you're good. You're unlikely to "get into trouble" unless you need to file an insurance claim, and find the coverage you paid for is null and void.

Comment: "120V service? That would be very rare and antique indeed, if it's even the case at all."  The point is that 240 volt appliances aren't standard equipment in USA homes, so much so that homes with natural gas service haven't seen a need to upgrade to 240V anything in the home for decades.  240V ovens are clearly an exception, and I stated as such in the question.  Your answer is not helpful as it starts with 240V being common in kitchens followed by a comment that implies actually using that 240V service for any appliances could be a code violation.

Comment: "Read the instructions. If they don't restrict to commercial or forbid residential, you're good."  That's good advice, and I'll take that into consideration on any purchase but I have a feeling that a 240V 3000W microwave oven is not among the items forbidden in homes.

Comment: "Electric stoves are overall more common in the U.S., with 68 percent of households owning one opposite 38 percent which have a gas stove" https://www.statista.com/chart/29082/most-common-type-of-stove-in-the-us/ and the violation is with most commercial appliances, not "any" appliance.

Comment: One problem with commercial *cooking* appliances is they assume commercial levels of smoke/fire detection and protection, ventilation, etc. which are hard to achieve in a typical residential setting. Of course, manufacturers take advantage of this by producing "prosumer" appliances that cost **more** than the equivalent commercial grade appliances (and twice or more what ordinary perfectly adequate residential appliances cost) but which are appropriately UL or ETL listed and are in fact designed to work with residential levels of ventilation, power supply, etc.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- generally speaking, that's more true for direct heating appliances such as ranges, conventional/convection ovens, and the like.  Commercial microwaves, OTOH, are often found in applications (break rooms, convenience stores) where they are used by members of the general public, so unless you're talking about a *seriously* heavy-duty microwave that's labeled expressly for use only by professional cooks, it'll be safe to use in your kitchen.  (And yes, I did read UL 923)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Agreed. But microwaves are an interesting one. Break rooms - most places I've seen just use the consumer grade stuff and replace it when it breaks. Convenience stores do have some very rugged machines that get a **lot** of use all day long. Googling: [this is it](https://funfoodthailand.com/product/panasonice-professional-microwave-1700w/). Might not be "every" 7-11, but looks similar to what I've seen locally. And only 1700W - that's a perfect fit for a 20A 120V circuit. OP is talking about 3000W, 240V - that's more like the kind of machine a caterer, restaurant, commissary

Comment: etc. might use to be able to get lunch ready for 200 people at a time. Very different type of equipment.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at a commercial restaurant supplier online and they did have some 240V "medium duty" machines in the 1.5-2kW range in addition to the heavy-duty 3kW stuff you mention (which could very well be restricted to professional cooks only by the UL standard -- this restriction is put in place to allow for higher exterior surface temperatures than the normal limits placed on an appliance accessible to the public)

Comment: Here's the USA version of that Panasonic commercial microwave oven that @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact linked to above: https://na.panasonic.com/us/food-service-systems/commercial-equipment/heavy-duty-microwaves/1700-watt-commercial-microwave-oven-0  That's at least close to what I had in mind.